# How to retain style tags saved in the contents in JCE?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3, joomla-article, joomla-content-editor

On my Joomla 3.3.0 site, I'm trying to write custom css rules in my article editor (JCE 2.3.4.4). I have disabled the 'html filtering' and now this is possible.

So now I get the desired output when I write something like:

```
<p>test</p>
<style>#t123{color:red}</style>
<div id="t123">red font</div>
```

However when I try to edit the article again, the `style` tag is missing. I can only see:

```
<p>test</p>
<div id="t123">red font</div>
```

How can I configure the editor to also show the `style` tag when editing?

Comment: Please post Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is to enable the `Allow CSS` option in `Components > JCE Editor > Editor Profiles > Editor Parameters > Advanced`

Thanks to @Apurv for giving me a hint on where to look for

Answer (score 1):

There are two places where you need to disable filtering. One is the `Global Configuration -> Text Filtering` and another is `JCE Editor Profiles -> Plug-in Parameters -> Media Support`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it guided me on where to look for. It is not correct as you have it. So if you edit it I can set it as the accepted answer